# Diagonalizable matrix and normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, diagonalization

I am looking at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20230/238980). After saying a matrix is idempotent it say it can diagonalize in this way:

$$V'QV = \Delta = \textrm{diag}(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{n-p \textrm{ times}}, \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{p \textrm{ times}})$$

Then he defines $K = V' \hat{\epsilon}$ (after having deduced $\hat{\epsilon} = Q\epsilon$) and says

> Since $\hat{\epsilon} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 Q)$, we have $K \sim N(0,
>  \sigma^2 \Delta)$ and therefore $K_{n-p+1}=\ldots=K_n=0$.

Can someone explain this passage?